# do not save check point for a final step for Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I use Estimator and I train model in the loop to feed data. Every step is the final step. The checkpoints are saved for every final step too. I want to avoid saving checkpoint in every iteration to increase the performance (speed) of the training. 
I can not find any information how to do this. Do you have any ideas/suggestions/solutions?

```
classifier = Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn,
    model_dir="./temp_model_Adam",
    config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(
        save_checkpoints_secs=None,
        save_checkpoints_steps=100,
        save_summary_steps=None
    )
)



# Train the model

for e in range(0, 10):
    numbers = np.arange(10000)
    np.random.shuffle(numbers)
    for step in range(0, 2000):
        classifier.fit(
            input_fn=lambda: read_images_for_training_as_batch(step, path, 5, numbers),
            steps=1
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays the api got changed a bit but from what I see you were using the fit  (currently train) method incorrectly, you should put steps=2000 and have your input function return an iterator over your dataset. Today you have tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn at your disposal that can help you when you have small data sets, otherwise you have to use tf.data.DataSet api.

Something like this (it loads .wav files):

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import audio_ops as contrib_audio
from tensorflow.python.ops import io_ops
# ...
def input_fn(num_epochs, batch_size, shuffle=False, mode='training')

    def input_fn_bound():
        def _read_file(fn, label):
            return io_ops.read_file(fn), label

        def _decode(data, label):
            pcm = contrib_audio.decode_wav(data,
                                           desired_channels=1,
                                           desired_samples=desired_samples)
            return pcm.audio, label

        filenames = get_files(mode)
        classes = get_classes(mode)
        labels = {'class': np.array(classes)}
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))

        if shuffle:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(labels))
        dataset = dataset.map(_read_file, num_parallel_calls=num_map_threads)
        dataset = dataset.map(_decode, num_parallel_calls=num_map_threads)
        dataset = dataset.map(lambda wav, label: ({'wav': wav}, label))

        dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
        dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)        # To load next batch while the first one is being processed on GPU
        iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        features, labels = iter.get_next()
        return features, labels

    return input_fn_bound

# ....

estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn(
        num_epoths=None, 
        batch_size=64,
        shuffle=True,
        mode='training'), 
    steps=10000)
```